# Concat string from 2d Array

Tags: c

I need a way to concat a string from a 2d array.
I started off creating a 50x50 2d array initialized with blank spots (aka " ". Just spaces). Then I filled each line up using fgets and each line has a array of characters which form a string.

For example

```
 H I   T H E R E
 H E L L O
 W O R L D
```

and the empty spaces are kept as spaces.

Now, when I print it, I need to print "HI THERE HELLO WORLD" without all the spaces after each individual string since each row is 50 spots long.

Here's what I have so far.

```
void printArray(char matrix[arraySize][arraySize]){
    int i,j;
    int tempArrayCounter =0;
    int tempArray[inputLineNumber * 50];
    for(i = 0; i< arraySize; i++){
        for(j = 0; j<arraySize;j++){
            printf("%c,",matrix[i][j]); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
    for(j=0; j< inputLineNumber;j++){
        for (i = 0; matrix[i][j] != '\0'; i++){
            tempArray[tempArrayCounter] =matrix[i][j];
            tempArrayCounter++;
        }             

    }         
    printf("%s\n", tempArray);
}
```

Ignore the first half of the function. All it does is show what the whole 50x50 2D array looks like.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT

I'll add the code I used to fill the arrays if it helps.

```
void readInput(char matrix[arraySize][arraySize]){
//inputLineNumber is the current row of the input
inputLineNumber = 0;

/*
 when the line is not empty, add the line into matrix
 */
char *p;
char currentline[arraySize];
fgets(currentline,arraySize, stdin);
if((p = strchr(currentline, '\n')) != 0){
            *p = '\0';
    }
while(strcmp(currentline, "\0")!=0){

    int k;
    int inputlength = (int)strlen(currentline);
    for (k = 0; k< inputlength ;k ++)
        matrix[inputLineNumber][k] = currentline[k];
    fgets(currentline,arraySize, stdin);
    if((p = strchr(currentline, '\n')) != 0){
            *p = '\0';
    }
    inputLineNumber++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clean up your code (use consistent indentation, remove unnecessary content, etc). Make it easy for me to help you, not hard :)

Comment: Sorry. I'm using VI for the first time and it isn't easy to keep it as clean as eclipse in my opinion :(

Comment: `gg=G` will indent everything in Vim

Comment: Would you also mind removing unnecessary code? (such as `printf("test1");`, etc)?

Comment: I'm currently using vi, not vim. Sorry about the unnecessary code. I'll clean that up asap.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your array to nul char (`'\0'`) instead of blanks, and use a loop to print every line as string.

Comment: I would love to initialize it with nul chars but unfortunately I can't. The code that creates the arrays were given to us.

Comment: Then when you fill it, put a nul char after the text.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mostly on the right track, but you need to make sure to do two things: make sure to properly null terminate the final array and make sure to insert spaces between lines.